# Is there any way to play real-time videos stream via video tag on Safari?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

I am trying to play real-time live stream videos such as webcam live video or Youtube live stream, not files, on Apple Safari via video tags(HTML5), but I have not succeeded yet.
I'd like to know if there is any way to make it possible.

I already have searched and found that Safari needs Range header from HTTP Response, but the problem is that real-time videos such as Youtube live streams are not files, therefore the Range(like file size) cannot be provided.
Really, there are no way to play live stream video on Safari???